# TFS 2013 after build does not run the unit tests, no errors

Tags: unit-testing

I am working on a web app, solution in VS2013 with several project in it, one of them is used for unit tests - Ms Unit test framework.  We have TFS 2013 set up to build the solution after each check in and trying to run the unit tests after each build.

From some reason unit tests are not executed after build, but also there is no error indicating that something broken or not found. I tried lot of things regarding editing the build definition - change the 'Test assembly file specification' to ***test*.dll, to use the exact dll name, changed the Target platform ...etc.

If I look into the log file I can see this:

> Run VS Test Runner 00:00:15 Inputs TestSpecs: BuildParameter[] Array
>   Enabled: True ConfigurationsToTest: OutDir: The RunTestsActivity was
>   invoked without a value for Platform or Flavor. The values Any CPU and
>   Debug were used.
>
> Test Run Completed. 0 tests executed.

What should I take a look, or what could be the problem ?

Comment: Are you using a framework such as nUnit or xUnit?

Comment: Microsoft testing framework is used

Comment: Are your UnitTests been build to the "Binaries" directory on the build agent's workspace?

Comment: Installation of Visual studio 2013 full version solved the issue. thx for the efforts anyway :)